# How to identify which DNS server is in use in Windows OS?

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system

I have a windows 10 machine with two network interfaces.

**Interface #1 (LAN Interface)**

IP: 10.1.0.5

Gateway: 10.1.0.1

DNS: 10.0.1.2

**Interface #2 (OpenVPN)**

IP: 192.168.1.5

DNS: 100.0.0.1

Note: My VPN is turned on with split tunnelling. Only traffic destined to 100.0.0.0/16 will go through the VPN

When I run the command `nslookup www.google.com`, which interface's DNS server is used as a default DNS?

Comment: Since `100.10.0.1` is not in the `100.0.0.0/16` network, there is no route to it and it cannot be used.

Comment: Just updated the OpenVPN DNS IP.

Comment: Windows will use the DNS of the route with the lowest metric. Just check your routes with `route print`.

Answer (score 2):

Run nslookup in interactive mode. That will show you what DNS server nslookup is using.

Comment: But on what basis it chooses the DNS server?

Comment: @Prado: Windows 10 queries DNS servers on all adapters in parallel. Additionally there is a feature called "Smart Multihomed Name Resolution" which may factor in. See: https://superuser.com/questions/969171/multihomed-windows-10-dns-resolution-timeouts